# Protecting Feet From Tanning

Tags: personal-care

I walk daily to my office in hot sunshine. The distance is about 2.5 KM's. We do not have formal wear so I prefer wearing Sandals as I am too lazy to wear shoes daily.

But, the problem is, on the exposed parts of my feet, I am having a dark tanning. What can cure this? And do any one have any hacks for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wearing sunblock on your feet. You probably don't need a very high SPF since you aren't in the sun all day, but high SPF is a good idea for long term skin health.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have many options. I would look into a more relaxed footwear like Toms shows or some type of slip on without being a thong style sandal.

However, if you only have thong sandals and want protection, as ErinGoBragh mentioned, you would want to wear sunblock (store bought, or natural)

Sesame oil resists 30% of UV rays, whereas coconut, peanut, olive, and cottonseed oils block out about 20%

Find a balance and good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Although not very stylish, you could wear socks.

Something like this wouldn't be very noticeable and would stop the tanning.
[image]

Comment: What about the smell it will produce?

Comment: Since they would be worn with sandals which are open to air circulation,  that shouldn't be a problem.  Also, natural fibers like cotton are better at not smelling than man made fibers like nylon or acrylic.

Comment: Thanks. +1 then. Unfortunately, since I don't have any reputation. I will request someone to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could wear gaiters. They are rather common at some folks:
[Guy wearing gaiters](https://www.google.de/search?q=dagobert%20duck&rlz=1C1ZMDB_deDE555DE555&espv=2&biw=1438&bih=968&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAWoVChMIrs-D26eNyAIVhdKACh3EagxN)